# Как новому слову попасть в словарь?

Tags: лексикография, неологизмы

Задумавшись как-то о синониме к длинному слову достопримечательность, я выбрал для себя - "прекраса"! Порывшись в сети, с удовольствием убедился - именно такое слово активно используется народом. 'Прекрасы нашего города' - типичный заголовок местных сайтов. Слово живет, но в словарях его нет! Неужели новейший неологизм, не попавшийся составителям словарей на глаза? Какие же критерии применяются в данных случаях, не пойму. Иностранщину привечаем, а от родных отворачиваемся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что Вы, какой же неологизм - просто безграмотность. Слово это давно известно, только пишется через И: [ссылка.](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/184248/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) 
  А новые слова постоянно включаются в словари, если употребляются в народе. Каждый год издаются выпуски неологизмов, статьи в специальных журналах. Нужна частотность их употребления - больше ничего.

Да,нашла, действительно много сайтов.И слово в разных значениях.Особенно понравилось "Гора Прекрас таит в себе как массу опасностей для туристов, так и массу прекрас". Гора Прекрас - гора красавиц, масса прекрас-масса красивого, прекрасного. Уральские прекрасы - красавицы и красоты одновременно.Слово, безусловно, красивое. Но не знаю, будут ли употреблять его вместо "красОты", это привычное общеупотребительное.А уж вместо книжного "достопримечательности" и вовсе сомневаюсь.Но, может, это тогда не неологизм, а малоупотребимое старое слово - синоним "красОты"? Тем более - если оно есть у Даля.
Кстати, на этих сайтах есть и вариант ошибок - явное значение "без прикрас"-неприкрашенная действительность.

Comment: Про имя знаю,но синонимом к слову "достопримечательность"? Чем же не подходит прикраса - украшение? Зачем ещё синоним? И с каким же значением - прекрасное здание? Но ведь это и есть украшение. А на каких  местных сайтах? Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку. Не видела ни разу.

Comment: Да, ссылок много. И синонимов к слову "достопримечательность" тоже:гордость,диво, чудеса, жемчужина, фишка, примечательность, я бы добавила красОты. Мне кажется, всё-таки используют чаще на сайтах слово в значении именно "красОты", "прекрасные места", а не в значении "примета города" ( сюда входит и плохое, и хорошее).

Comment: Мне нравятся прекрасы. Но все-таки прекрасы (красоты) вдобавок к прикрасам (украшениям) будет лишним. И как потом разобраться с орфографией? У нас есть уже прИуменьшить и прЕуменьшить (кстати, во время ответа оба слова программа подчеркивает как неверные).

Comment: Это так. Я тоже  считаю, что будет только путаница. К тому же,может, мы с вами просто не знаем, что оно уже есть в каких-то словарях - областных например.Надо идти в научную библиотеку, у меня вот  нет. А в общеупотребительный словарь всё же вряд ли войдёт - слово непривычное для современности, вызывающее вопросы употребления и орфографии.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, ни разу не встречала его в широком употреблении в русском языке — от Вас слышу впервые. "Прикраса" — по-украински это "украшение", но чтобы в сети — и часто...